# Aptana won't launch - error after choosing Workspace folder

Tags: java, logs, aptana-studio

I am on Ubuntu Disco 19.04 and have installed Aptana via the [.zip file](https://github.com/aptana/studio3/releases).

I've also installed Java [via instructions here](https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-19-04/).

When I launch the .exe from my Aptana folder, I get the Splash Screen, then select the workspace folder. However, after that then get an error:

> AptanaStudio3
>   An error has occured. See the log file
>   /home/[user]/Aptana/Aptana_Workspace/.metadata/.log

However, I don't see any files in the `Aptana_Workspace` folder, via the File Explorer and/or via Terminal (`ls` when in the `Aptana_Workspace` directory).

What might be preventing the Aptana to launch?

Comment: show hidden files to see the .metadata